# How to group rows (bassed on CustomerID) using Pivot in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, bids

I am practicing SSIS and currently working on Pivot transformation. Here's what i am working on.
I created a Data Source (Table name: Pivot) with the following data.

[image]

Using SSIS, i created a package for Pivoting the data to have the following columns

PersonID --- Product1 --- Product2 --- Product3.

Here's where am at, I was able to create the pivot data to text file. But The output is not grouped by PersonID.

My Current Output is

[image]

As we can see the Transformation does not group the based on 
SetKey(PersonID : PivotUsage =1)

The output i am hoping to get is

[image]

Where the data is grouped based on PersonID.

What am i missing here?

Edit:
Going back to the example i was following, I re-ordered the input data as follows.

[image]

Does the Input data need to be in this order/pattern, every time? Most of the examples i came across follow the similar pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the input data needs to be sorted by whatever you're pivoting on:

> To pivot data efficiently, which means creating as few records in the
>   output dataset as possible, the input data **must be sorted** on the pivot
>   column. If the data is not sorted, the Pivot transformation might
>   generate multiple records for each value in the set key, which is the
>   column that defines set membership. For example, if the dataset is
>   pivoted on a Name column but the names are not sorted, the output
>   dataset could have more than one row for each customer, because a
>   pivot occurs every time that the value in Name changes.

That's a direct quote from the [Pivot Transformation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140308%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) documentation on MSDN. (Emphasis added.)

Comment: Hmm.... Ok, will go thru the material. 
But if we don't have control/access over the input data, if there an alternative to using pivot. To get a similar result?

Comment: If you have no control over the source data, you can place a sort transformation upstream of the pivot. You'll need enough memory to sort the entire set. If it's a large set and you don't have enough memory, you could also bulk load to a table, then use that as the source with an order by in the query (or create a clustered index on the sort key column), IsSorted set to true, and the SortKeyPosition set appropriately.

Comment: @brian: Thanks for that input. I will practice those two transformations with pivot.
Then my flow dig would be something like this
Source > Sort > Pivot > Destination ?

Comment: @TanmoyDB: Yes, that should be fine. If you do run into memory issues, see the 2nd half of my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

When I first read this answer, I thought that the sorted column should be the one with PivotUsage=2 in the pivot.  That's what I understood the pivot column to be.  However, what finally worked for me was to sort by a column with pivot usage=1.  It's a column I would group by if writing the sql by hand.